TYPO3: Linkhandler in redirects extension
I've configured a linkhandler for news. Works fine, when linking via rte/ckeditor.
But when creating redirects via the redirects module, the linkhandler tab doesn't show up.
TYPO3 12.4.22
PHP8.2
Any ideas?

Needs to be added / allowed by adjusting the TCA of the redirects table. However, there is an open issue regarding record linkhandlers within the redirects module:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/105648
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/102892

Use something like
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_redirect']['columns']['target']['config']['allowedTypes'] = "['page', 'file', 'url', 'record', 'yourlinkhandler']";

in your TCA/Overrides/somefile.php. Replace "yourlinkhandler" with the name of your linkhandler.
Thanks Stefan Bürk for the hint.
